# How can I assign value to an structure from another structure?

Tags: c++, xcode

I have two structs as following:

```
 struct command{
     string name;
     int time;
 };
 struct job{
     queue<command*> tasks;
     int ID = 0;
     jobState *table = NULL;
     int time = 0;
 };
```

Now I want to assign values to my structures:
What I have done so far is:

```
 job a;
 a.time = 20;
 a.ID = 2;
```

My problem is I cannot assign value to 'tasks' which is in 'job' structure but use 'command' structure's variables.

Comment: Do you really need *pointers*?

Comment: What does "use 'command' structure's variables" means? What do you mean by "cannot assign"?

Comment: I think I will need a pointer for future purposes.

Comment: I have a struct named 'command'. I want to assign values to variables 'name' and 'time'  by using queue<command*> tasks from struct job. I hope I am clear enough

Comment: For the pointers, It is not clear from the code provided what owns the object pointed to by the pointer.  A [mcve] would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not to use a pointer to `command` as the struct is fairly simple.

```
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
struct command{
     std::string name;
     int time;
 };
 struct jobState {} *jobtable = nullptr;

 struct job{
     std::queue<command> tasks;
     int ID = 0;
     jobState *table = NULL;
     int time = 0;
     void AddCmd(std::string name, int t) {
       tasks.push(command {name, t});
     }
 };
```

or if you want to assign all at one time something like this could work

```
     std::queue<command> x {{{ "Clean up", 42 }, { "A mess", 63}}};
     job a { std::move(x), 2, jobtable, 20 };
```

See it at [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/554TEx)

If you want to continue with your pointer and you are the owner of the `command` then you should use `std::unique_pointer` which should be something like this

```
     queue<std::unique_ptr<command>> tasks;
     ...
     auto AddCmd(const std::string& name, int time) {
       return tasks.emplace(std::make_unique(name, time));
     }
```

Comment: Thank you.I used: job a {{{ "Clean up", 42 }}, 2, jobtable, 20 }; and deleted my pointer
and I got the following error: No matching constructor for initialization of 'queue<command>'